# Where do my yielded items go when I'm scraping a website?

Tags: python, scrapy, generator, yield

I'm using scrapy to crawl websites. I have this block of code that erases the existing data in my data.json file:

```
with open('data.json', 'r+') as f:
   if f:
      f.truncate(0)
```

Then, I yield data to item containers:

```
items['price'] = price
items['name'] = name
yield items
```

At the end of the function, I make a request to the next url in my list:

```
yield scrapy.Request(next_url, callback=self.parse)
```

I noticed that all of the data writes to the file as soon as the crawler stops. I was wondering how the data that I scraped was stored. Would it be stored in as a generator and then accessed at the end, after all of the recursion is done? Or am I doing things twice in a row; that is, yielding my data and then going through the code again to yield the request? I think this is more of a lack of understanding about generators, so any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing you code, I can only assume your data was stored only in memory. If you are only yielding the items without a pipeline to handle them, the simplest way to store those items would be to use the feed export. You can do it by executing your spider like this:

```
scrapy crawl my_spider -o my_data.csv
```

*It supports other extensions (json, xml, ...), you can read more about the feed export [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-exports).*

Another way to do it would be to write a [pipelines](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#item-pipeline) to handle your items and store them in files/database/anywhere you want.